# Will TypoScript be replaced with YAML in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, yaml, typoscript, typo3-8.x

The system extensions `form` and `ckeditor` are using YAML as configuration language instead of TypoScript which is used everywhere else.

Will TypoScript vanish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2 mentioned extensions are using YAML also because the form extensions has a history in Neos which uses YAML and the ckeditor uses YAML itself.

---

There are no plans in the core to actually drop TypoScript completely, however YAML has some advantages which are very important:

- It is a configuration language known and used in the outside world of TYPO3
- It has well known parsers and tests

Therefore it might be that completely **new configurations** might be done in YAML as well.

Especially with the usage of Fluid, ViewHelpers, the usage of TypoScript dropped - at least for me - a lot and I am very happy about it. However `page.10 < styles.content.get` will stay for a while ;)